# Draw a circle with 6 Images

Tags: android, android-drawable

I've to show something like this in app. And I also have image in same size. But I'm confuse how I'll place images like this to draw a circle

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00nRa.jpg)

I've draw a circle with 4 images
[code link](https://gist.github.com/imran-samed/4ecd9553718cb9479d49da9ace633d6f)

Comment: Show your code where you started to place one partial image on some background.

Comment: @blackapps https://gist.github.com/imran-samed/4ecd9553718cb9479d49da9ace633d6f
Please check this gist. I'm successfully able to create a cricle with 4 images.

Comment: I wonder if you can cut a pizza in four which problems you encountered trying to cut it in six pieces. You did not explain that.

Comment: @blackapps if u checked my code , then u can see, I have used 4 LinearLayout to draw a circle using ARC...
But If I try to use 6 LinearLayout for same,  its not working. I m confused how I could place image besides to each other to draw a circle so that it will work on all screen sizes.

Comment: There is no code. Behind the link is an xml layout i see now. I had not expected that.

Comment: You are building up a circle using image views in layouts. You could have told that at the start. You are drawing nothing.

Comment: @blackapps yes you are  right, can I draw circle using 6 images or is there any other way..
bcox I have to manage their click events too...